# Matplotlib: how to update the figure title after user has zoomed?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way to **update the title** of a Matplotlib figure after the user has zoomed in? For example, I would like the title to display the exact extends of the x-axis,

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10,step=0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

f = pl.figure()
pl.plot(x,y)

def my_ondraw(ev):
    x1,x2 = f.gca().get_xlim() # FIXME value hasn't been updated yet
    pl.title("x = [%f, %f]" % (x1,x2))

f.canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', my_ondraw)

pl.show()
```

As noted, my code doesn't get the right values back from get_xlim() because the re-draw hasn't been done at the time my_ondraw is called...

Any suggestions?

---

Modified code that **works** based on Ilya's suggestion below:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10,step=0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

f = pl.figure()
ax = f.gca()
pl.plot(x,y)

def my_ondraw(ev):
    print "my_ondraw: %s" % ev.name
    x1,x2 = f.gca().get_xlim() # FIXME value hasn't been updated yet
    pl.title("x = [%f, %f]" % (x1,x2))

ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', my_ondraw)

pl.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register callback functions on the `xlim_changed` and `ylim_changed` events. Try something like this:

```
def on_xylims_change(axes):
  x1,x2 = f.gca().get_xlim() # FIXME value hasn't been updated yet
  pl.title("x = [%f, %f]" % (x1,x2))

fig, ax = pl.subplots(1, 1)
ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', on_xylims_change)
ax.callbacks.connect('ylim_changed', on_xylims_change)
```

You can read more about it here: [Event handling and picking in Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html).

Comment: Yes, it works. The documentation is pretty terrible on this particular point, however, as it doesn't make it at all clear that 'xlim_changed' exists, and how to connect events to it. But your example set me straight. Thank you!